# MySQL Workbench Executing Script on Server - Error #1064

Tags: mysql, workbench

I've spent a few hours looking at the manual and need help now correcting the below erros. Thank you.

**LOG:**
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ACTION')

ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 17

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`Patients`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Patients` (
      `PatientKey` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `MiddleName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
      `doctors_DoctorKey` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`PatientKey`),
      INDEX `fk_Patients_doctors1_idx` (`doctors_DoctorKey` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Patients_doctors1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`doctors_DoctorKey`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`doctors` (`DoctorKey`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO 'ACTION')
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch

**What I'm working with:**

Server type: MySQL

Server version: 8.0 - MySQL Community Server(GPL)

MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `ACTION`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `VISIBLE`......

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `VISIBLE`; it is not valid in the version you are running.